# cpanel how to access public_html

Tags: php, cpanel

I created all my files in public_html directory.Now that directory is missing.Now my cpanel is looks as a screen shot.I don't know where to create my files.

[image]

Comment: due to somebody hacked my site all our domain is cleaned

Comment: If someone hacked it, there's not really much we can do.

Comment: is any solution to create it again

Comment: Well, then we are not web hosting provider. Submit a ticket to your web hosting provider.

Comment: Usually you could just name it 'public_html' again,if that doesnt work contact your web hosting provider

Comment: Ok I try it and let you know.

Comment: it's working.But it doesn't created cgi folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You will have to contact your hosting provider. They will check this and if they have a backup of your account, then they will restore your all files from backup.